# How to extend a class with 2 generic Types and get Spring to Autowire instance

Tags: java, spring, generics, autowired

I have a class that extends 2 other class as seen below.

```
public class EJBHandler<T extends EJBObject, I extends EJBHome>
```

(The EJBObject and EJBHome comes from the javax.ejb artifact)
The idea behind this was so that I could just use Spring to specify the exact instance and Spring would autowire the instance for me like in the following example.

```
@Autowired
    private EJBHandler<SystemUser, SystemUserHome> systemUserEjb;
    @Autowired
    private EJBHandler<Authentication, AuthenticationHome> authenticationEjb;
```

But when attempting the above I get the following error:

`Expected 1 type argument on generic interface.remote.EJBHandler<?, ?> but found 2`

I have searched for a solution but none of them seem to work. Among them that I thought had the best chance of solving the problem was the following method.

1. In the `EJBHandler` class have a constructor that would determine the class types using Spring's built-in GenericTypeResolver (as seen below). This solution builds but it seems like when actually used the `systemUserEjb` is null and never initialized.

```
    protected Class<T> ejbObject;
    protected Class<I> ejbHomeClass;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void EJBHandler() {
        ejbObject = (Class<T>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(getClass(), EJBHandler.class);
        ejbHomeClass =(Class<I>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(getClass(), EJBHandler.class);

        if(useExternalDependencies) {
            try {
                Object homeObject = createHomeObject(ejbObject.getSimpleName(), "SomeServerHere");
                this.homeObject = (I) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(homeObject, ejbHomeClass);
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

 protected Object createHomeObject(String jndiName, DeployedServer server) throws NamingException {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext(getProperties(server));
        Object homeObject = ctx.lookup(jndiName);
        log.debug("Found [{}] bean in context on server [{}].", jndiName, server);
        return homeObject;
    }
```

What I did then was to create a concrete class to extend the `EJBHandler` class and in the constructor just inject the class objects and it works then?

**My Question is:** why since in my head it should do the same thing without having to have a concrete class that does nothing except just tell the superclass the Type of T and I?

Comment: Apparently, according to `GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument`, the generic types are unresolveable. If you put a breakpoint and trace the method you will see this is why it returns null.

Comment: Don't attempt to make coexist `EJB` (especially with Homes and Objects) and `Spring` together. It will fail.

Comment: why do you say that @MarcLeBihan